# como pasar de una pagina a otra con php todos los datos de unos checkbox

Tags: php, html

Tengo una pagina con una serie de checkbox, los cuales son generados con php pues son formados dependiendo de la cantidad de ficheros que hay en una carpeta.

al darle al boton submit, quiero poder mostrar en otra pagina cuales son los checkbox pulsados.

se os ocurre alguna idea?

Comment: Hola Sergio, tenemos poca información para ayudarte. Generalmente, es buena práctica platicar sobre qué has intentado realizar para solucionar el problema, también puedes compartir código fuente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues con algo así:

```
<form method='post' id='userform' action='thisform.php'> 
   <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option One'>1<br>
   <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Two'>2<br>
   <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='Option Three'>3
   <input type='submit' class='buttons'> 
</form>
```

Y en el php:

```
<?php 

      $miArray = $_POST['checkboxvar']; 
      for($i=0; $i < count($miArray ); $i++){
         echo "Seleccionado " . $miArray [$i] . "<br/>";
      }

?>
```

Los ejemplos los he sacado de StackOverflow en inglés:
[Stack1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026361/php-multiple-checkbox-array)
[Stack2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516847/make-array-from-checkbox-form)

Comment: estupendo!!! muchas gracias!